# Resizing page - Div in place using percentage based width

Tags: html, css

So I have a div that stick at the top right hand corner of my screen.

I can make the div stay at the top right hand corner using the following CSS:

```
.dockbar {
    background: #000000;
    width:300px;
    float:right;
    position: absolute;
    left:1180px;
    top:10px;
    height:38px;
}
```

But I hate this approach because the div has space to the right if the screen is larger. I would prefer to using percentage based sizing, but doing that causes the div to move with the screen (because of the percentage..)

Is there a way to position a div at the top right hand corner:

- Without using fixed positioning
- Without declaring exact pixel based positioning

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `left:1180px;` to `right: 0px` and everything should work fine.

```
#wrapper{
 width: 800px;
}

<div id="wrpper">
   <div class="dockbar"></div>
</div>
```

Something like this, maybe.

Comment: As 0 is not a measurable unit there is no reason to add px, em, % etc, just saves space.

Comment: One problem - It still moves when the page resizes. I want the div to remain at (say) 1100px left even when I resize. I just dont want to have to declare a position for that div - I'd rather say "Go to the 100% right and that's your position, regardless of resize"

Comment: @Ryan McDonough Sorry, I read `"Can't just use right...."` and thought it was posted by the author.

@g1021maxED `Wrap` your content in a div and set the width you want. Then add that `.dockbar` with right: 0 relatively to the `wrapper`.

Comment: @g1021maxED You can't have it 1110px to the left and directly to the right as well, you can set a width of 1110px and have it right aligned?

Comment: Maybe I'm not wording it right (sorry about that). If I open the browser in a 800x800 screen (lets say). I want the div to position absolute right of the screen at 800. Then when I resize, it stays at 800, regardless of resize